# Activator.CreateInstance calling constructor with class as parameter

Tags: c#, reflection, activator

Hi I'm trying to do the following dynamically
I'm using my own CreateInstance method but this has been tested with Activator.CreateInstance

```
IPEndPoint newObject = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 80);
```

when I try to use activator I get error, cannot convert System.RuntimeType to IPAddress

```
    public static object CreateInstance(Type context, object[] Params)
    {
        List<Type> argTypes = new List<Type>();

        foreach (object Param in Params)
            argTypes.Add(GetType(Param));
        ConstructorInfo[] Types = context.GetConstructors();
        foreach (ConstructorInfo node in Types)
        {
            ParameterInfo[] Args = node.GetParameters();
            if (Params.Length == Args.Length)
            {
                bool[] cond = new bool[Params.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < Params.Length; i++)
                    if (argTypes[i] == Args[i].ParameterType) cond[i] = true;
                if (cond[0] == true & cond[1] == true)
                    return node.Invoke(Params);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This is what the Params look like in the array
[0] {Name = "IPAddress" FullName = "System.Net.IPAddress"}
[1] 80

this is the calling code, prob should have provided it before so you know what I'm trying to do as you can see it parses string values that represent classes, this is why I can't use typeof or typeconstraints.

```
private object CreateInstance(ObjectCreationExpression Exp)
{
    object context = GetContext(Exp.Identifier); //Gets the class type
    Type t = (Type)context;
    object[] Params = GetParams(Exp.ArgumentList).ToArray();
    object newObject = Activator.CreateInstance(t, Params);
    return newObject;
}

public static object GetContext(string classname)
{

    return ParseNamespace("System.dll", classname);
}

private static object ParseNamespace(string Namespace, string classname) //Looks up class in System.dll
{
    string DotNetPath = ToolLocationHelper.GetPathToDotNetFramework(TargetDotNetFrameworkVersion.VersionLatest);
    Assembly Asm = Assembly.LoadFile(DotNetPath + @"\" + Namespace);
    Type[] Types = Asm.GetExportedTypes();
    foreach (Type Node in Types)
    {
        if (Node.Name == classname)
            return Node;
    }
    return null;
}

private List<object> GetParams(NodeCollection<ArgumentNode> Params)
{
    List<object> Arguments = new List<object>();
    foreach (ArgumentNode node in Params)
    {

        if (node.Expression is MemberAccessExpression)
        {
            MemberAccessExpression exp = (MemberAccessExpression)node.Expression;
            Type value = (Type)GetContext(exp);
            string name = DirectCast<IdentifierExpression>(exp.Right).Identifier;
            if (value.IsEnum)
            {
                string[] names = DirectCast<Type>(value).GetEnumNames();
                Array item = DirectCast<Type>(value).GetEnumValues();
                Arguments.Add(item.GetValue(names.ToList().IndexOf(name)));
            }
            else
            {
                Type item = value.GetMember(name)[0].ReflectedType;
                Arguments.Add(item);
            }
        }
        else
            Arguments.Add((Int32)ParseType(node.Expression));
    }
    return Arguments;
}
```

ObjectCreationExpression is a custom class that contains parsed sourcecode for creating a new instance, the two main properties are ArgumentList which is a collection of values or identifiers to be used as parameters, the other property is an identifier for the type we are creating

Comment: You're passing a `Type` object, not an actual `IPAddress`, as your first parameter. Without seeing the calling code, we have no way of knowing how this state of affairs came to be.

Comment: You say you get the 'cannot convert' error when you use `Activator.CreateInstance` but you haven't said what the problem is with your `CreateInstance` method.

Answer (score 1):

You have wrote a nice implementation to create object instance, however it had some flaws. I've corrected them in the code below

```
    public static object CreateInstance(Type context, params object[] Params) // params keyword for array
    {
        List<Type> argTypes = new List<Type>();

        //used .GetType() method to get the appropriate type
        //Param can be null so handle accordingly
        foreach (object Param in Params)
            argTypes.Add((Param ?? new object()).GetType());
        ConstructorInfo[] Types = context.GetConstructors();
        foreach (ConstructorInfo node in Types)
        {
            ParameterInfo[] Args = node.GetParameters();
            if (Params.Length == Args.Length)
            {
                bool[] cond = new bool[Params.Length];
                //handle derived types
                for (int i = 0; i < Params.Length; i++)
                    if (Args[i].ParameterType.IsAssignableFrom(argTypes[i])) cond[i] = true;
                if (cond[0] && cond[1])
                    return node.Invoke(Params);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

- paramaters were not an array
- Param.GetType() is more appropriate
- handle parameter of derived types(maybe buggy at this moment as value types and class type need to be differentiated)

calling code

```
IPEndPoint newObject = (IPEndPoint)CreateInstance(typeof(IPEndPoint), IPAddress.Any, 80);
```

**Note** I may not be able to correct every flaw in the sample above, I just made it workable for your scenario i.e. you calling code

**Generics implementation**

```
    public static T CreateInstance<T>(params object[] Params) where T : class // params keyword for array
    {
        List<Type> argTypes = new List<Type>();

        //used .GetType() method to get the appropriate type
        //Param can be null so handle accordingly
        foreach (object Param in Params)
            argTypes.Add((Param ?? new object()).GetType());
        ConstructorInfo[] Types = typeof(T).GetConstructors();
        foreach (ConstructorInfo node in Types)
        {
            ParameterInfo[] Args = node.GetParameters();
            if (Params.Length == Args.Length)
            {
                bool[] cond = new bool[Params.Length];
                //handle derived types
                for (int i = 0; i < Params.Length; i++)
                    if (Args[i].ParameterType.IsAssignableFrom(argTypes[i])) cond[i] = true;
                if (cond[0] && cond[1])
                    return (T)node.Invoke(Params);
            }
        }
        return default(T);
    }
```

calling code

```
IPEndPoint newObject = CreateInstance<IPEndPoint>(IPAddress.Any, 80);
```

**Fully dynamic object construction**

```
    public static object CreateInstance(Type pContext, object[] Params)
    {
        List<Type> argTypes = new List<Type>();

        //used .GetType() method to get the appropriate type
        //Param can be null so handle accordingly
        if (Params != null)
            foreach (object Param in Params)
            {
                if (Param != null)
                    argTypes.Add(Param.GetType());
                else
                    argTypes.Add(null);
            }

        ConstructorInfo[] Types = pContext.GetConstructors();
        foreach (ConstructorInfo node in Types)
        {
            ParameterInfo[] Args = node.GetParameters();
            // Params can be null for default constructors so use argTypes
            if (argTypes.Count == Args.Length)
            {
                bool areTypesCompatible = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < Params.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (argTypes[i] == null)
                    {
                        if (Args[i].ParameterType.IsValueType)
                        {
                            //fill the defaults for value type if not supplied
                            Params[i] = CreateInstance(Args[i].ParameterType, null);
                            argTypes[i] = Params[i].GetType();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            argTypes[i] = Args[i].ParameterType;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!Args[i].ParameterType.IsAssignableFrom(argTypes[i]))
                    {
                        areTypesCompatible = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (areTypesCompatible)
                    return node.Invoke(Params);
            }
        }

        //delegate type to Activator.CreateInstance if unable to find a suitable constructor
        return Activator.CreateInstance(pContext);
    }
```

calling code

```
IPEndPoint newObject = (IPEndPoint)CreateInstance(typeof(IPEndPoint), new object[] { IPAddress.Any, 80});
```

this code can also null parameters

eg

```
IPEndPoint newObject = (IPEndPoint)CreateInstance(typeof(IPEndPoint), new object[] { IPAddress.Any, null});
```

I simplified it a bit and also handled null parameters for default constructors also. and couple of other checks

so this change makes it complete dynamic even you can `construct value types` too

eg

```
int obj = (int)CreateInstance(typeof(int), null);
```

**Example for your case**

```
object context = GetContext(Exp.Identifier);
Type t = (Type)context;
object[] Params = GetParams(Exp.ArgumentList).ToArray();
//use the above defined method and it will work as expected
object newObject = CreateInstance(t, Params);
```

Comment: Get rid of the `if(cond[0] == true...` check. That appears to be debugging code. It can't be right for general-purpose object creation.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, unfortantly I can't use typeof or Type Constraints<> because this is supposed to be dynamic and would be used on other classes not just IPAddress.

Comment: I hope you can pass any class using it, it is not restricted to IPAddress or any other thing. however for being complete dynamic you can change the parameters to `(object[] Params)` and pass the parameters like this `new object[]{ IPAddress.Any, 80}`. I can create a sample if you require so.

Comment: @pushpraj, if this is a stab at producing a generic `CreateInstance` implementation the `if (cond[0] && cond[1])` check seems awfully case-specific.

Comment: Also you're checking whether a specific parameter is assignable from the given arg type (you're using those terms backwards), but the arg type is effectively changed via `Param ?? new object()`. `null` would be a perfectly valid argument for a constructor which has a parameter of type `string`, for example, but `new object()` - not so much.

Comment: i just updated it for better handling see `Fully dynamic object construction` in the answer. Try it and see if this fullfil all your needs.

Comment: @pushpraj I checked your example it doesn't solve the dynamic issue, you would need to know in advance that the type is going to be IPAddress, this project is designed for executing sourcecode instructions so you can't use fixed statements like typeof(IPAddress); as it will only work for that type.

Comment: it is not fixed for `typeof(IPAddress)` it is just an exmple. you can pass any `Type`. I request you to execute it with your expected parameter. you can see the signature of the method is same as yours `public static object CreateInstance(Type context, object[] Params)` so it will definitely work the way you expect it to be. Just give it a try.

Comment: @user3786721 I added an example for your use case. Let me know if you are still not able to use it your expected way. I used `typeof(IPAddress)` to retrieve the type of IPAddress it can be replaced as in added example. In short you do not need to know the `Type` in advance you can pass the type retrieved from `GetContext` method

Comment: @pushpraj your example is identical to mine, it's not the method context that's the problem its the first argument, its being passed as a Type I need to pass it as an object. This is the source of the problem `{
                Type item = value.GetMember(name)[0].ReflectedType;
                Arguments.Add(item);
              }`

Comment: @pushpraj I figured it out I replaced GetMember with GetField().GetValue(); It's working now, thankyou for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, this is my refactoring of your method:

```
public static object CreateInstance(Type pContext, params object[] pArguments) {
   var constructors = pContext.GetConstructors();

   foreach (var constructor in constructors) {
      var parameters = constructor.GetParameters();
      if (parameters.Length != pArguments.Length)
         continue;

      // assumed you wanted a matching constructor
      // not just one that matches the first two types
      bool fail = false;
      for (int x = 0; x < parameters.Length && !fail; x++)
         if (!parameters[x].ParameterType.IsInstanceOfType(pArguments[x]))
            fail = true;

      if (!fail)
         return constructor.Invoke(pArguments);
   }
   return null;
}
```

Note that you seem to have the notion of "parameter" and "argument" backwards. A "parameter" is the named part of the method that accepts a value. An "argument" is the actual value that you pass.

Aside from that, it sounds like your problem has more to do with the values you are passing, than the implementation of the method.